# python3 - how to Simplifying multiple if/else statements

Tags: python-3.x

Using more than one nested if/else makes the logic bloated.

How can I simplify the following code.

The more than one nested if/else format and logic is pretty ugly.

---

```
payload_dict = {"process": None, "status": None, "taskId": task_id,
                "jenkinsJobName": job_name, "msg": None}

if srv_result == "failed":
    if result:
        logging.info("srv start failed")
        response_data = {"errorMsg": "failed", "errorCode": "2", "serviceList": result}
        _msg = json.dumps(response_data, ensure_ascii=False)
        payload_dict.update(process=1, status=0, msg=_msg)
        logging.info(f"Requests：{payload_dict}")
    else:
        logging.info("srv start failed")
        response_data = {"errorMsg": "failed", "errorCode": "2",
                         "serviceList": "srv start failed"}
        _msg = json.dumps(response_data, ensure_ascii=False)
        payload_dict.update(process=1, status=0, msg=_msg)
        logging.info(f"Requests：{payload_dict}")
else:
    if result:
        logging.info(f"failed srv：{result}")
        response_data = {"errorMsg": "failed", "errorCode": "1", "serviceList": result}
        _msg = json.dumps(response_data, ensure_ascii=False)
        payload_dict.update(process=1, status=0, msg=_msg)
        logging.info(f"Requests：{payload_dict}")
    else:
        logging.info("deploy success.")
        response_data = {"errorMsg": "sucess", "errorCode": "0", "serviceList": result}
        _msg = json.dumps(response_data, ensure_ascii=False)
        payload_dict.update(process=1, status=1, msg=_msg)
        logging.info(f"Requests：{payload_dict}")
```

Comment: Refractor it into methods handling results. The problem here are not nested conditions, but repetitive code.

Answer (score 2):

A bit improved.

```py
payload_dict = {"process": None, "status": None, "taskId": task_id, "jenkinsJobName": job_name, "msg": None}

stat = 0

if srv_result == "failed" and result:
    logging.info("srv start failed")
    response_data = {"errorMsg": "failed", "errorCode": "2", "serviceList": result}
elif srv_result == "failed":
    logging.info("srv start failed")
    response_data = {"errorMsg": "failed", "errorCode": "2", "serviceList": "srv start failed"}
elif result:
    logging.info(f"failed srv：{result}")
    response_data = {"errorMsg": "failed", "errorCode": "1", "serviceList": result}
else:
    logging.info("deploy success.")
    response_data = {"errorMsg": "sucess", "errorCode": "0", "serviceList": result}
    stat = 1

_msg = json.dumps(response_data, ensure_ascii=False)
payload_dict.update(process=1, status=stat, msg=_msg)
logging.info(f"Requests：{payload_dict}")
```